# Using a special email regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have some emails in the form:

```
staticN123@sub1.mydomain.com
staticN456@sub2.mydomain.com
staticN789@sub3-sub.mydomain.com
```

The dynamic is the number after the (N or M or F) character, and the subDomain between the @ and mydomain.com

I want to make a regular expression that matches this form in a string, and if it's a match, get the number after the N character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
staticN([0-9]+)@.+\.mydomain\.com
```

instead of `[0-9]+` you can also use `\d+` which is the same.
the `.+` after the @ could match too much. eventually you'd like to replace that with `[^\.]+` to exclude sub.sub domains.

update:

```
^staticN(\d+)@[a-z0-9_-]+\.mydomain\.com$
```

adding `^` and `$` to match *start* and *end* of the search string to avoid false match to e.g. somthingwrong_staticN123@sub.mydomain.com.xyz

you can test this regexp here [link to rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/WFWXKJ7GVF)

--

applying changes discussed in comments below:

```
^(?:.+<)?static[NMF](\d+)@[a-z0-9_-]+\.mydomain\.com>?$
```

code example to answer the question in one of the comments:

```
// input
String str = "reply <staticN123@sub1.mydomain.com";
// example 1
String nr0 = str.replaceAll( "^(?:.+<)?static[NMF](\\d+)@[a-z0-9_-]+\\.mydomain\\.com>?$", "$1" );
System.out.println( nr0 );
// example 2 (precompile regex is faster if it's used more than once afterwards)
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "^(?:.+<)?static[NMF](\\d+)@[a-z0-9_-]+\\.mydomain\\.com>?$" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( str );
boolean b = m.matches();
String nr1 = m.group( 1 );  // m.group only available after m.matches was called
System.out.println( nr1 );
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick help, i have one more question though: is that the name before mydomain.com can only be in the forms sub1 or sub1-sub2 meaning letters or digits only or letters or digits separated by a dash, got me ?

Comment: `staticN(\d+)@[a-z0-9_-]+\.mydomain\.com` 

this will restrict the subdomain to only lowercase, number, '_' and '-'

Comment: thanks again for the quick feedback, have one question though : how to get the digit after N character with a java code, is it with the regular substring method or there's another way? and one last question is that I want my regex to be applicable also to something like : reply <staticN123@sub1.mydomain.com>

Comment: `^(?:reply <)?staticN(\d+)@[a-z0-9_-]+\.mydomain\.com>?$` this would allow optional 'replay <' at the start and optional '>' at the end.

Comment: what about if the reply word can be anything not static ?

Comment: would i replace it with (.*) or what ?

Comment: use `(?:.+ <)?` instead of `(?:replay <)?` if you write `(.*)` this will be you first group in the result ( see code example '$1' or 'm.group£(1)' ). The brace are used to indicate the groups. If the opening brace is followd by '?:' this pair of brace doesn't create a group in the result

Comment: btw, can you please change the example to work on the two forms : 1- reply <staticN123@sub1.mydomain.com> 2- staticN123@sub1-sub.mydomain.com